# My site is showing up as desktop on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I just created a website using BootStrap and I'm not sure why the desktop version is showing up on mobile devices. What could be the possible reasons this would happen? I made sure to have all the necessary BootStrap files linked in my HTML files including 'Bootstrap.min.css,' 'Bootstrap.min.js,' and jquery link. This is the [site](http://www.ericarodriguez.me/music). Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner pull-right" >
        <div class="active item">

            <img src="" class="img-responsive pull-left">
       </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="" class="img-responsive pull-left">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           <img src="" class="img-responsive pull-left">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `viewport` meta tag in your site. Add this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And to prevent the users to zoom in or out, use this to lock the zoom (you should do):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

More info: [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). Without this, modern phones will display the same layout as in desktop.

Comment: OMG! I missed that completely. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, of course! I was going to do it earlier, but it said I had to wait awhile before I can accept your answer. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GoDaddy and have enabled "forward with masking" for the domain, the site will be forwarded using iFrames.  This will cause your responsive mobile website to show up as a desktop version on an iPhone.  Here is a great resource (blog), I found that can show you how to setup domain forwarding correctly when using AWS and GoDaddy as your hosting provider.